# jQuery Posting to ASP.NET MVC Controller Action - Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

What am I doing wrong? The does not hit the action and the error is a 405 - >The HTTP verb POST used to access path "somepath" is not allowed.

Client Script

```
 $.post('/DecisionPoint/ApplicationState', { fileName: fileName, stateString: e });
```

filename is just a 'string' as is 'e'

Controller Action

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveApplicationState(string fileName, string stateString)
{
            string filePath = GetDpFilePath(fileName);
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.Load(filePath);
            HtmlNode stateScriptNode =
                htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/script[@id ='applicationState']");
            stateScriptNode.InnerHtml = "var applicationStateJSON =" + stateString;
            htmlDocument.Save(filePath);

            return Json("State Updated");


}
```

**UPDATE**

This is my global.asax.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "DecisionPoint", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{fileName}/{stateString}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "DecisionPoint", action = "ApplicationState", fileName = UrlParameter.Optional, stateString = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
      );
```

The error is now - Resource not found. The script lives in the standard /Scripts folder that the template creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is your path to the control and action?

```
Controllers/DecisionPoint/SaveApplicationState
```

Because normally the word "Controllers" doesn't show up in the URL path, and that is what jQuery needs the exact URL path for accessing this action.

Try just this:

```
string url = "/DecisionPoint/SaveApplicationState/" + filename + "/" + e;
jQuery.post(url);
```

The problem is you have mapped the route to an exact URL, so in order to post to that action, you need to recreate the URL.  Also please note, I don't know if this is intentionally or not, but you action name is `SaveApplicationState` however in the route mapping you have the action listed as `ApplicationState`.  This needs to be consistent.

Comment: That doesn't work because the code you just posted in the question changes the whole approach to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the url to which you are posting is not correct.  In Asp.net MVC, you do not post directly to controllers, you post to a route that usually resolves to a controller.  So, for example, if I had a controller called `DecisionPointController` with an action (method) called `ApplicationState` (I dropped the word "Save" to be more [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer), then the corresponding url would be:
`~/DecisionPoint/ApplicationState`.

Comment: I have a taken your advice and changed the action to 'ApplicationState' I updated my question to show my global.asax file. I don't understand why the url is incorrect.. I changed it to '/Controller/Action' still no good

Comment: No worries!  In the code above, you are attempting a `POST`, not a `GET`.  By doing so, you are passing the values (`fileName`, and `stateString`) in the request, not in the url.  This means you do not need a separate Route.  Check out [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx) by Scott Guthrie for more information regarding basic routing and how Controllers work.  If you remove the custom route, does it work?  Also, just as an FYI, routes are matched in order, so always put custom routes above default routes.